# Open url and stay in app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to open any url in app and stay in app like this done in Skype. It opens safari page with "done" button in top left corner but you still in Skype.Can anyone help me?
[image: Example]

Comment: you can open any web page in your `UIWebView` within your app.

Comment: I know it, but in Skype it seems like you opened Safari but stay in app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example your are showing is using the [`SFSafariViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/). This will show Safari in your app, this class is available in iOS 9 or newer.

You could use a check like this if you plan to support versions lower then iOS 9:

```
if ([SFSafariViewController class]) {
    SFSafariViewController *viewController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    WebViewController *viewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.url = url;
    [self presentNavigationControllerWithViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Here `WebViewController` is just a view controller with a `UIWebView` that will load the page. You can create your own tool bar like `SFSafariViewController` to go back/forward or open in Safari.

Comment: Thank you bro, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open any web page within your app,

Create `UIViewController` subclass and follow the steps

1. Add Property for url (NSString or NSURL)
2. Add "Done" Button on navigation bar (dismiss the view controller on click)
3. Add UIWebView
4. load the request in WebView in viewDidAppear

To open page from other ViewController:

```
WebViewController *webVC=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebViewControllerIdentifier"];
webVC.url=@"http://example.com";


[self presentViewController:webVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply `SFSafariViewController`. This is the simplest way to achieve what you want. I believe Skype uses exactly that. You can put it inside `UINavigationController` or whatever another container view controller

[SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/)